# Need mysql query on how to get data from mysql table with month and year column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have mysql table with below columns. I am given startDate and endDate and now I have to fetch rows between those dates. Can some one please help with mysql query with how I can get those rows?

For example if startDate is November 2021 and endDate is March 2022. Then query should select rows with the months between these dates.

| month | year | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09 | 2021 | 30 |
| 10 | 2021 | 40 |
| 11 | 2021 | 90 |
| 12 | 2021 | 10 |
| 01 | 2022 | 25 |
| 02 | 2022 | 15 |
| 03 | 2022 | 89 |

Comment: How exactly are your startDate and endDate values stored?

Comment: Like you are literally given the words `'November'` and `'March'`? Please clarify

Comment: As already requested!! We need to know how the startDate is presented to you. Is it `November 2021` all in one string? Is it `11 2021` all as one string? Is it in 2 seperate strings like `November` and `2021`? Is it ..... well i hope you get it by now

Comment: I get these startDate and endDate from api written in javascript and I can modify them as required but I cannot modify this table to add more columns as this is used in multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step would be to compute a column with a proper DATE value, starting from the column you have.
For example, `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year,'-', month, '-', 1), '%Y-%m-%d')` will return a proper SQL date on the 1st day of the year-month that you consider.

This value can then be compared (with `<=` and `>=`) with the limit dates (as requested in the comments, the answer depends on how those are represented).

Answer (score 0):

You can compare tuples in MySQL:

```
select month, year, `values`
from tbl
where (year, month) >= ('2021', '12')
  and (year, month) <= ('2022', '03');
```

Another way is combining year and month to a single string:

```
select month, year, `values`
from tbl
where concat(year, month) between ('202112') and ('202203');
```

This only works if year and month (at least month) are zero-filled strings.